# TSQL order data according to dates

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

Hi and thank you for your response in advance. I am new to TSQL and currently in an internship. 
I am creating a web page using VB and I have no problem displaying what is in the first table below 
to the user.

```
----------Name--------------------Date----------------Points

1--------Mike---------------------10/01/2012----------4

2--------Mike---------------------10/05/2012----------2

3--------Mike---------------------10/03/2012----------1

4--------Mike---------------------10/17/2012----------4

5--------Mike---------------------10/24/2012----------4

6--------Simon---------------------11/05/2012--------1

7--------Simon---------------------11/11/2012--------3

8--------Simon---------------------11/20/2012--------4

9--------Simon---------------------11/22/2012--------2

10  Simon   11/27/2012  3
```

However, I have a drop down list with day and week which sorts the Data from the first 
table above on a day to day or week to week interval.

Output when user selects to display data in weekly intervals starting from the `MIN(Date)` to 
`MAX(Date)` for each Name in table should be like this. I use

```
SELECT  Name, MIN(Date) AS StartDate, DATEADD(DD, 7, MIN(Date)) AS EndDate, SUM(Points)
```

And I know I shouldnt set the EndDate to a fixed point like that because then the next 7 days
of data will not show.

```
-----Name-------StartDate-------EndDate---------Points

1----Mike-------10/01/2012------10/05/2012----------7

2----Mike-------10/17/2012------10/24/2012----------8

3----Simon-----11/05/2012-----11/11/2012----------4

4----Simon-----11/20/2012-----11/27/2012----------9
```

Any help will be much appreciated. I hope I was clear in my question. Thanks!

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks the question is not clear?  What is your question without all this information, show us data and expected results with a small summary of what those expected results just did.  Very simple.

Comment: @JonH I'm with you, I'm not too sure what's being asked.

Comment: I don't see a single question mark in the question.

Comment: Sorry guys! I have a table with points associated with each name and the date the points were earned. So there can be multiple rows for a single person on the same day for different value points earned. How would I sort this data so display how many points earned in a seven day (one week interval) for each person. Is that any clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I got your question clear.

For getting sql records based on a range of dates you may use the [BETWEEN](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/between.php) operator

Like this:

```
SELECT Name, MIN(Date) AS StartDate, MAX(Date) AS EndDate, SUM(Points)
FROM people
WHERE Date between to_date ('2003/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
AND to_date ('2003/12/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd') 
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY Points;
```

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: You mention the "BETWEEN operator", but you don't use `BETWEEN`. You mean `greater than or equals` and `lesser than or equals` operators? Or did you really mean to use `WHERE order_date BETWEEN startingdate AND endingdate`?

Comment: I did use between. I also mentioned a link for further reading.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I do use WHERE Date BETWEEN but I do not want rows for ever day in the last 7 days. I want to add all the points earned for a person within the last 7 days and display it in a single row. And then the next 7 days for that person in row number 2 and so on.

Comment: You must have still been editing your post, because when I posted my comment it used `>=` and `<=`, which are the operators I mentioned in my comment above (and did not use `BETWEEN` other than in the link text); that's what prompted my comment in the first place.

Comment: @user1860688 Sounds like you want a GROUP BY instead.